# I can't create public inherited class - Something is wrong with constructors C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Hey there fellow programmers, I'm having a big issue with this thing! I just want to create a class that inherits stuff from previous class, but the problem is that in both class I have constructors and the compiler just won't compile this simple code - It's telling me - 10.12.2012.3.cpp:28:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘Monitor::Monitor()’: Please Ignore the main fuction - It's not doing anything in particular, sine I can't get past this problem :/ Sorry for dumb question, but I couldn't find the specific answer PS: my first post here :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Monitor
{
    protected:

        int sifra;

    public:

        Monitor (int sifra1)
        {
            sifra = sifra1;
        }

};



class Prodaja : public Monitor
{
    protected:

        int monster;    

    public:

        Prodaja (int monster1)
        {
            monster = monster1;
        }

};

int main()
{
    int sifra1;
    string firma1, model1, dobavitelj1;
    float nabava1, cena1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Monitor` does not have a [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

You have to invoke its constructor in the constructor of the derived class. That's because otherwise the `Prodaja` instance doesn't know how to construct its `Monitor` part.

So you need

```
Prodaja (int monster1): Monitor(monster1)
```

or to define a constructor of `Monitor` that takes no parameters (or has a default parameter).

Comment: So theoretically if I would have a Monitor's default constructor created and besides him Second constructor, I wouldn't have to invoke him in the derived class right? Or this isn't a good practice? PS: Thank you man, I appreciate your fast response, it solved my problem instantly.

Comment: Yes, if you have what's called a "default constructor", see the link in the answer, then that one will be called implicitly on construction of the derived instance, unless you explicitly call the second constructor as I did above. Whether is good/bad practice depends on the design. The default constructor needs to to minimal initializations so that the created object is in a valid and well defined state, and can be used safely.